# canvas object not able to reload/refresh css while changing the .css file using condition

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using custom css for an object in canvas,using 2 css file and changing the source file using condition but css change is reflecting while I am selecting the object,can it be done instantly?

Comment: I don't know it but python's [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fabric/info) tag doesn't seem to be anyhow related with any *canvas* thing. So first of, did you mean [fabricjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fabricjs/info)? This confusion could have been avoided by adding an [MCVE] which is required for such questions seeking help on debugging. And moreover when it's really not clear what you mean. It's ben a long time I didn't check all new features of fabricjs, but I really doubt there is a way to style its rendered objects with css.

Comment: I am using fabric text box where I am loading custom font,so font family I am defining in a css file,at the time of changing font I am using the different font which is defining in a other css file because I want the font family name same but font source will be changed, at the time i am changing the source file canvas can not refreshing but when I am clicking on the text box it changing the font.

Comment: can you please tel me is there any way to refresh canvas object?

Comment: for >  v1.7.0 , use `object.dirty = true` then in next `renderAll()` call object will refresh